# How to resolve ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, langchain

I'm working with Node.js and utilizing the `Langchain` package.
Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
import "dotenv/config";
import { ChatOpenAI } from "@langchain/openai";

const chatModel = new ChatOpenAI({
  openAIApiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY,
});

const response = await chatModel.invoke("hello");
console.log(response);
```

I've encountered the following error and I'm trying to resolve it:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './utils/function_calling' is not defined by "exports" in C:\REWORD\server\node_modules\@langchain\core\package.json imported from C:\REWORD\server\node_modules\@langchain\openai\dist\chat_models.js
```

I've installed the latest versions of @langchain/core and @langchain/openai packages.

and here is my package.json code

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@langchain/openai": "^0.0.23",
    "langchain": "^0.1.30",
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@langchain/core": "0.1.5"
  }
}
```

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has any insights on how to troubleshoot this problem, I'd greatly appreciate your assistance!